# Set scroll position inside div element to bottom?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a div element in a text-based game I'm coding that is where you see your previous commands and the return text from your actions, and I want to have a scroll bar inside the div, which I made, but the scroll bar doesn't change position when content is added, so you stay at the top, so I need a way to set the scroll inside the div to the bottom whenever content is added. My HTML is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#contentWrapper{
 border-color:crimson;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 height: 400px;
overflow: scroll;
    position:relative;
}
content:{
height: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id = 'contentWrapper'> 
  <div id = 'content'> 
  <p>  content </p>
             
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with JavaScript. Depending on how you get the results you have to edit it to your own needs. If you reload the page every time an answer has been given, then you can keep the code as is. If on the other hand you get the results and the next question via Ajax, then on the response function you should always find the div again and rerun the JS code every time a new result is available

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("contentWrapper");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
#contentWrapper{
  background-color:red;
  border-color:crimson;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position:relative;
}
content:{
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'contentWrapper'> 
  <div id = 'content'> 
    <p>  content1 </p>
    <p>  content2 </p>  
    <p>  content3 </p>
    <p>  content4 </p>   
    <p>  content5 </p>
    <p>  content6 </p>   
    <p>  content7 </p>
    <p>  content8 </p>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The content is added through the course of the game with no page reloads by a function I called add(), which accepts the string you want added as a parameter and puts that into a string which is appended to the innerHTML of the content div

Comment: as i said, on the same function add() you put the JS code inside.